# Writing a text between TOC and first content

Tags: table-of-contents

[image: beforeafter]

Hello, i want to add a text between TABLE OF CONTENTS (İÇİNDEKİLER) and ÖNSÖZ like given above. Codes are given below. Is there any way to solve this problem? Thank you.

```
%%% Automatically generated.
%****************************************
% TABLE OF CONTENTS
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{İÇİNDEKİLER}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % dots for chapters
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\MakeUppercase\hfil\bfseries\fontsize{14pt} 
{14pt}\selectfont}
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\mdseries}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\mdseries}
%\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{CHAPTER\space}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{:}

\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{10mm} 
\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{3\baselineskip} 
%\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{7em} 
%\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum}

%%% Spacing between items
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{\cftbeforechapskip}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{\cftbeforechapskip}

\begin{singlespace}
\tableofcontents
\end{singlespace}
\clearpage
%........................................
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought that:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\hfill Stuff\par}
\tableofcontents
```

would put `Stuff` above the page numbers in the ToC.